# Support Vector Machine with zero bias term

Tags: machine-learning, svm, algorithms, libsvm, kernel-trick

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve SVM with zero bias term. So dual form of such SVM is $max_\alpha \sum_i^n \alpha_i -1/2\sum_i^n \sum_j^ny_iy_jK(x_ix_j)\alpha_i\alpha_j$
subject to: $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq C, \forall i = 1,2,...,n $.

The only difference between this SVM and original SVM is we don't have $\sum_i^ny_i\alpha_i = 0$ constraint. Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this?

Kindly point out me to either some paper that I can implement (with values K precomputed) or some toolbox that can do this (with values K precomputed and bias term zero).